# Bing map not loading smoothly , i am using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bing-maps

Bing Maps ajaxv7, not loading smoothly in bootstrap modal, i also made edit to the existing
css and also deleted img{ max-wdith:100% } in bootstrap.css but of no use. Only a single    tile is zooming and remaining tiles are remained blur

```
.bing img{
 max-width:none;
 }
<div class="bing" id="mymap" />
```

here is 
  problem only occurs in chrome browser

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem in your sample using Google Chrome latest version. You should check the height of the map and you can also specify the size of the control in the constructor call (dynamically based on the real size of the element)